# Cleanup and Burninate the [ethics] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Most questions tagged with [ethics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ethics) are completely opinion based and could be closed as such.

Perhaps some of the questions that have good answers should be migrated to another site. For example maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009885/should-a-company-prevent-employees-from-publishing-an-app-in-an-appstore-in-thei) could be moved to [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)?

Once any off topic questions are closed the tag should be burninated.

Comment: Questions can't be migrated after 60 days (without special exceptions).

Comment: @KevinBrown True, I forgot about that.

Comment: YES!  Burn ethics!

Comment: There are no remaining ethics questions left open: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bethics%5D+closed%3Ano

Comment: [tag:ethics] has been burninated and should be removed from the system in a few hours.

Answer (score 16):

Pulling the questions from ["When to burninate"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/159034) for [ethics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ethics)

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Yes, most of the questions involve ethical/philosophical situations and programming. It's not ambiguous (but that's up to personal interpretation), though it is a bit broad as you can see by looking at the popular tags.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

I'm going to say no. Ethical questions tend to be very opinion based, and those kinds of questions are off topic for Stack Overflow. Here are some examples:

- [An Ethical Question: Is it wrong to re-use other sites' user inputted data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4395606/359284)
- [What are the ethical issues with using analytics in Mobile Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3858914/359284)
- [When a co-worker steals credit from your project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19411808/359284)
- [Java, Web Pages, Ads and Revenue - Ethics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22537615/359284)

Many of these questions are looking for answers that realistically only lawyers can give. Those questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, and they are the kind of questions that this tag attracts.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Aside from making it a sign post for an opinion based question that can probably be closed, not really. Lots of questions have ethical side issues that usually aren't mentioned, and those are fine, but a question with only the [ethics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ethics) tag would clearly be off-topic.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

There is a bit of personal opinion involved in ethical questions, but for the most part the meaning is clear.

---

So after looking over the [ethics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ethics) questions, I believe that it should be cleaned up and burninated, as we expected. Almost all questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, and those which aren't can be given better tags.

After looking at the questions, I also found some broken windows in [legal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/legal), [copyright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/copyright), [3rd-party-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-library), and [licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/licensing). These might need individual burnination requests if they don't already exist.